# Unable to start jenkins on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I'm trying to start jenkins with the command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-47:/etc/init.d$ sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start
 * Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins
```

But when I try to check where it's running with:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i jenkins
```

I get nothing

How can I start jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to start Jenkins on Ubuntu (16.04 and 18.04) is using:

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

To verify if the service is running you can use

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```